# MIN MAX and all values comma separated SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have the following problem: I have a table with employees and emails.

- employee1 received 7 emails
- employee2 received 4 emails
- .
- .

Now I need for the employees the max date, the min date and all receivedates of the emails in one column in a comma-separated format.

I have the following:

```
SELECT ... 
FROM
   (SELECT 
        MAX(Datum) as MDatum, MIN(Datum) as MinDatum,
        Sender, Betreff,
        CASE 
           WHEN MIN(Datum) = MAX(Datum) 
              THEN MIN(Datum) 
              ELSE dbo.explode(datum) <- my problem
        END AS VALUE,
        Nummer
    FROM 
        #NEWTABLE 
    WHERE 
        not nummer IS NULL
        AND Sender <> ''total'' 
    GROUP BY 
        Sender, Betreff, Nummer, datum <- second problem
         ) x 
PIVOT 
    (max(VALUE)
         FOR [Nummer] IN (' + @cols2 + ')
    ) p
```

`@cols2` are the dynamic employees

When I group by datum, I only get the max(value) in pivot

How could I solve that?

kindest regards, frank

ADDED:

here is my table(#NEWTABLE):[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwtfS.png)

```
Nummer |    Betreff |             Datum |
----   | ----       | ----              |
1       2.000 EUR Rente   06.03.2017
1       2.000 EUR Rente   NULL
1       2.000 Rente       04.03.2017
1       2.000 Rente       12.02.2017
1       2.000 Rente       12.03.2017
1       2.000 Rente       19.02.2017
1       2.000 Rente       19.03.2017
1       2.000 Rente       27.02.2017
1       2.000 Rente       NULL
1       2.000 Rente       27.02.2017
1       2.000 Rente       NULL
2       2.000 EUR Rente   06.03.2017
2       2.000 EUR Rente   NULL
2       2.000 Rente       04.03.2017
2       2.000 Rente       12.02.2017
2       2.000 Rente       12.03.2017
2       2.000 Rente       19.02.2017
2       2.000 Rente       19.03.2017
2       2.000 Rente       27.02.2017
2       2.000 Rente       NULL
2       2.000 Rente       27.02.2017
2       2.000 Rente       NULL
```

so you have nummer, that is employe, betreff and datum, the received date

expected ouput should be:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nr31.png)

```
nummer  mindate     maxdate     alldates
1       12.02.2017  19.03.2017  12.02.2017,
                                19.02.2017,
                                27.02.2017,
                                27.02.2017,
                                04.03.2017,
                                06.03.2017,
                                12.03.2017,
                                19.03.2017
2       12.02.2017  19.03.2017  12.02.2017,
                                19.02.2017,
                                27.02.2017,
                                27.02.2017,
                                04.03.2017,
                                06.03.2017,
                                12.03.2017,
                                19.03.2017
```

kindest regards, frank

Comment: please add some sample table data and the expected result - as well in formatted text. 
Also show us your current query attempt

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `FOR XML PATH('')`:

```
SELECT Nummer,min(Datum) miDat, max(Datum) maDat,
       STUFF( (SELECT ','+char(10) + CONVERT(char(10),Datum,104) FROM #tmp 
               WHERE NOT Datum is null AND Nummer=o.Nummer
               ORDER BY Datum
               FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '' ) as dates 
FROM #tmp o GROUP BY Nummer
```

The `STUFF()` function simply takes away the first two characters.

A working demo can be found here:
http://rextester.com/PUG64308

(I changed the sample data a little bit in order to get slightly different results for the two numbers.)

**Edit:** your changed result can be easily achieved by modifying the query in the following way:

```
SELECT min(Datum) miDat, max(Datum) maDat,
       STUFF( (SELECT ','+char(10) + CONVERT(char(10),Datum,104) FROM #tmp 
               WHERE NOT Datum is null AND Nummer=1
               ORDER BY Datum
               FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '' ) as dates1,
       STUFF( (SELECT ','+char(10) + CONVERT(char(10),Datum,104) FROM #tmp 
               WHERE NOT Datum is null AND Nummer=2
               ORDER BY Datum
               FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '' ) as dates2
FROM #tmp
```

although in my opinion the columns "Sender" and Betreff" do not make sense anymore in such a result scenario.

A working example can be found here: http://rextester.com/EATE35782

Comment: Very nice @cars. +1

Comment: perfekt @cars10

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps

```
;WITH cte_Table (Nummer,Betreff,Datum) AS
(
SELECT 1,'2.000 EUR Rente',CAST('2017-03-07' AS DATE) UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'2.000 EUR Rente',NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'2.000 Rente','2017-03-04' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'2.000 Rente','2017-02-12' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'2.000 Rente','2017-03-12' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'2.000 Rente','2017-02-19' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'2.000 Rente','2017-03-19' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'2.000 Rente','2017-02-27' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'2.000 Rente',NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'2.000 Rente','2017-02-27' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'2.000 Rente',NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'2.000 EUR Rente','2017-03-06' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'2.000 EUR Rente',NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'2.000 Rente','2017-03-04' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'2.000 Rente','2017-02-12' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'2.000 Rente','2017-03-12' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'2.000 Rente','2017-02-19' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'2.000 Rente','2017-03-19' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'2.000 Rente','2017-02-27' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'2.000 Rente',NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'2.000 Rente','2017-02-27' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'2.000 Rente',NULL
)
,cte_MinMax(nummer,mindate,maxdate) AS
(
SELECT Nummer,MIN(Datum),MAX(Datum)
FROM cte_Table
GROUP BY Nummer
)
,cte_CSV AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT a.Nummer, STUFF((    SELECT ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),b.Datum,104) AS [text()]
                        FROM cte_Table b
                        WHERE a.Nummer = b.Nummer
                        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '' ) AS alldates
FROM cte_Table a
)
SELECT b.nummer,b.mindate,b.maxdate,a.alldates 
FROM cte_CSV a
JOIN cte_MinMax b
ON a.Nummer = b.nummer
```

Answer (score 1):

it works like a charme...
but i made a mistake, sorry, the expected output should look like this(with pivot)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goDKf.png)

```
sender | betreff | mindate      | maxdate     | 1             | 2
blubb  | blah    | 12.02.2017   | 19.03.2017  | 12.02.2017,   | 12.02.2017,
                                                19.02.2017,     19.02.2017,
                                                27.02.2017,     27.02.2017,
                                                27.02.2017,     27.02.2017,
                                                04.03.2017,     04.03.2017,
                                                06.03.2017,     06.03.2017,
                                                12.03.2017,     12.03.2017,
                                                19.03.2017      19.03.2017
```

kindest regards, frank

Answer (score 0):

i got it:

```
SELECT ... 
FROM
   (SELECT sender,Nummer,min(Datum) MinDatum, max(Datum) MDatum,betreff,
                    STUFF( (SELECT '',''+char(10) + CONVERT(char(10),Datum,104) FROM #NEWTABLE 
                    WHERE NOT Datum is null AND Nummer=o.Nummer and sender = o.sender and betreff = o.betreff
                    group by Datum,sender,Nummer,betreff
                    ORDER BY Datum
                    FOR XML PATH('''')), 1, 2, '''' ) as VALUE 
                    FROM #NEWTABLE o where sender <> ''total'' GROUP BY sender,Nummer,betreff
         ) x 
PIVOT 
    (max(VALUE)
         FOR [Nummer] IN (' + @cols2 + ')
    ) p
```